# Task.Run fails to process awaited methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asynchronous, salesforce

We are running into a situation where have a requirement to start and execute few launch and forget threads during a call. Though, our call fails to execute if the async methods have any awaited call.

Here is an example. Are we missing something?

```
public class SomeClass
{

    public async Task Test()
    {
        //Calling synchronously this things works
        await Save(1).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await Save(2).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await Save(3).ConfigureAwait(false);

        //Starting three threads at the same time fails while trying to run var queryResult = await SomeClient.QueryAsync<T>(q).ConfigureAwait(false);
        _ = Task.Run(async () => await Save(1));
        _ = Task.Run(async () => await Save(2));
        _ = Task.Run(async () => await Save(3));
    }

    public async Task<bool> Save(int ct)
    {
        var x = await Update(ct).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return x;
    }

    public async Task<bool> Update(int ct)
    {

        await _someObject.CallingSomeAsyncMethod<dynamic>("Some Query").ConfigureAwait(false);

        await _someObject.CallingSomeAsyncMethod<dynamic>("Some Query").ConfigureAwait(false);

        await _someObject.CallingSomeAsyncMethod<dynamic>("Some Query").ConfigureAwait(false);

        return true;
    }
}

public class SomeObject
{

    public async Task<T> CallingSomeAsyncMethod(string q)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(false);
        //OR Any async method which is awaited here just stops the execution

        return queryResult;
    }
}
```

Comment: By fails to execute, do you mean that the method isn't even getting called? If you put a breakpoint in `Save`, does it not get hit?

Comment: The save() is getting called but it stops execution after await SomeClient.QueryAsync<T>(q).ConfigureAwait(false); is hot by the first thread. The other issue is that i am not able to capture any errors. never reaches the catch block (if a try catch is placed on queryAsync method

Comment: How does your QueryAsync method look like? Do you have any `await`s in there or are you just starting task and returning it?

Comment: QueryAsync is DeveloperForce.SaleForce.ForceClient Method (third Party Lib) to execute queries on sales force

Comment: To be honest, I can't reproduce your situation by replacing QueryAsync with e.g. Task.Delay(). I can catch exceptions and all of the code runs fine. There must be some sort of hang happening in your 3rd party lib, maybe it can't connect and it's just waiting to timeout.

Comment: How is `Test` being called?

Comment: in this example i have just used test to show that running multiple task run invokes failure. The Task.Run is invoked in from our .net core controller..we incoke the controller get some stuff and return back and in the same action we just fire and forget the Task.Run

Comment: Maybe the third-party library does not support multiple concurrent requests. Is there any documentation, or someone that you can ask about the inner workings of this library?

Comment: I have adjusted the code.it is not just the third party stuff any await inside the 'CallingSomeAsyncMethod' method breaks the thread. and i am not able to capture any exceptions. would love some suggestions on that JohanP

Comment: The problem now seems related on how the `Test()` is called. Can you show the calling code?

Comment: Right now i am just running it from a unit test method (XUnit)

Comment: @fireholster Copying your exact code into a console app gives me the expected results. I cannot reproduce your issue. As Theodor Zoulias said, the issue must be how the code is being called.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run multiple tasks at the same time you should call the methods without the `await` and hold the task. Then you can do `await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3, ...);`

Comment: We are not looking to run bunch of tasks together. The example is from a test class. We have to run in on separate threads as each task run comes from UI

Comment: If you "must" run them on separate threads you shouldn't use TPL. There is no guarantee of new threads.

Comment: what should we use?